# Meaning of the "votes to close" history?

Tags: support

Just now I looked at [Derivatives of norm of vector-valued holomorphic functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269048/derivatives-of-norm-of-vector-valued-holomorphic-functions) which was showing a vote to close. However, looking at the history of "close votes" https://mathoverflow.net/review/close/history
I can only see three votes since the question was open, including mine, and they all voted for open.

Is it the case that this "close history" only shows people voting AFTER an initial vote to close, or is that initial vote also listed?

Comment: I will add to the information provided the review is also shown on the [timeline of the post](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/269048/timeline), but only after *the review is finished*. All closures and re-openings of the question are shown both on timeline and in [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/269048/revisions). (As a side note: @StefanKohl I think that your comment actually answers the question - so it probably could be posted as - or expanded to - an answer.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Is the timeline of a post linked somewhere, or does one need to manually enter the URL to see it?

Comment: @StefanKohl Manually. Probably the easiest way is to modify the link revision history - if that link is available (i.e., if the post was edited). See also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The close votes review history records only reviews, i.e. close votes which are cast directly and not from review are not listed. This means that a question can get closed without any trace of it in the review history -- this happens if 5 votes are cast before the question enters the review queue and someone votes on the review. It may even happen that the review records 3 times "leave open", but the question gets closed anyway.